# transfer files in/out of HDFS via ssh tunnel

Tags: hadoop, ssh, ssh-tunnel

A bit of a complicated set up:

I have the following structure

```
localhost --> bastion_host -> server -> hadoop_cluster
```

Now I am able to create an ssh tunnel that allows me to copy files from `localhost` and `server`. Once in server, I can always use `hadoop fs -put/get` to transfer files in a out of the cluster. But the cluster is not visible from anywhere else apart from `server`

Is there a way of copying files in and out of the cluster using the existing tunnel?

I was under the impression that I could use"

```
ssh -p 2345 localhost "hadoop fs -put -/user/eron/test_file3" < testing_scp.txt
```

where 2345 is the local port for the tunnel and testing_scp.txt is a local file.

I get, however,

> "sh: hadoop: command not found"

so the command is not executed on `server`

Answer (score 3):

When you ssh server, $PATH is updated by executing .bashrc, .profile, etc. As you use a tunnel, /usr/local/hadoop/bin is not added to your $PATH

It should work specifying the hadoop binary path:

```
ssh -p 2345 localhost "/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop fs -put -/user/eron/test_file3" < testing_scp.txt
```

Comment: that seems to work ok, but what about retrieving the file from hdfs?

Comment: ¿? Same binary, same issue, same fix.

Answer (score 1):

```
ssh -p 2345 localhost "hadoop fs -put -/user/eron/test_file3" < testing_scp.txt
```

use hypen before put

Comment: nope, same thing, "hadoop: command not found" That was a typo on my post, let me correct it

Comment: there can be a path error u can change directory to hadoop/bin which has all commands for hadoop .

Answer (score 1):

Very late obviously but as I was looking for the same thing (especially the extracting) so wanted to document this for my future self:

Per the other answers putting the file in can be done via

```
ssh -p 2345 localhost \
   "/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop fs -put - /user/eron/test_file3" \
   < testing_scp.txt
```

Or alternatively:

```
cat testing_scp.txt  | \ 
  ssh -p 2345 localhost "/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop fs -put - /user/eron/test_file3
```

Getting it out is pretty much the same:

```
ssh -p 2345 localhost \
   "/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop fs -cat /user/eron/test_file3" \
   > local_file.txt
```